# How to implement refresh token in react js

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, axios, httponly

The response from the server set the access and refresh token to the client(reactjs) as an httponly cookie. How can I use the refresh token to generate another access token, because when I try to use `document.cookie` or `cookie.get('refresh')` it returned undefined.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/', {
    refresh: cookie.get('refresh') // Cookie here is undefined
}).then(response => {
    // new access token
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. As its httponly cookie. you dont have access to get it with javaScript. if the backend set it well. it will save on your cookies by default and transfer between cliend and server on each httpRequest with **no specific configuration**. Also you can check httponly cookie on your browser console cookies. (it should have httponly green tick icon)
**So what should you do next for generate another access token?**
you need to implement an interceptor.
**how?**
these documentations will help you.
[enter link description here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/09/25/react-axios-interceptor-to-set-auth-header-for-api-requests-if-user-logged-in)